# 'Missing 500.shtmlController' when submit a form with the words "select" and "from" in any text-box in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This one threw me for a loop - not even sure where to start looking.

If you submit a form in my CakePHP application with the words "select" and "from" in any text area, it errors out:

```
Missing Controller

Error: 500.shtmlController could not be found.

Error: Create the class 500.shtmlController below in file: app/controllers/500.shtml_controller.php

<?php
    class 500.shtmlController extends AppController {
        var $name = '500.shtml';
    }
?>

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_controller.ctp
```

Even if you type "selected blah fromy", it will error.  BUT - if you type them in reverse order, it's not a problem - you CAN type "from select blah blah ...etc" and it's no issue.

I'm using the jquery validator plugin (but I have to assume it's not on the javascript side - seems like it must be something w/ Cake / MySQL?)

ANY thoughts very welcome.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with CakePHP, but I'm going to assume that it's some sort of problem with SQL injection -- probably some basic protection against it that's misconfigured. The error you're getting is CakePHP trying to render a 500 error page -- which is a general server-side error, the kind one might throw if one thought an SQL injection attack were occurring -- and failing to render it because you haven't defined a 500 Error Page view/template.

Comment: @RileyDutton: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have ModSecurity installed on Apache? It looks like your string triggers its pattern:

```
(insert[[:space:]]+into.+values|select.*from.+[a-z|A-Z|0-9]|select.+from|bulk[[:space:]]+insert|union.+select|convert.+\\(.*from)
```

Look for something like `ModSecurity: Access denied with code 500 (phase 2)` in your error log.

And it looks like you've disabled default `Pages` route:

```
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

so Cake tries to route request for domain.com/500.shtml to `500.shtmlController`.

Comment: Sure enough.  Called my host, and they said I can white-list specific areas if I need to to allow certain form(s) to pass ModSecurity.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually two problems.

1. Your rewrite rules aren't working quite right if they're trying to pass a request for the "static" page `500.shtml` to Cake. Make sure that your .htaccess files are in place and that Apache is configured with `AllowOverride` so that the .htaccess files can do their job properly.
2. Something is screwy with the code causing an internal server error when processing your posted data. To troubleshoot this, we'll need to see the code that you're POSTing to. Revise your question to include the relevant controller code.

Answer (score -1):

Try to migrate to CakePHP 1.3. I think you are using CakePHP 1.1.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1561/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3

Comment: Per the tag on the question, I'm in Cake 1.3